# NameError: name 'zombie_array' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, testing

I have a python code (q4.py) given below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def DFS(j, visited, zombies, row):
    for k in range(row):
        if zombies[j][k] == '1' and visited[j][k] == False and visited[k][j] == False:
            visited[j][k] = True
            visited[k][j] = True
            DFS(k, visited, zombies, row)


def zombieCluster(zombies):
    row = len(zombies)
    col = len(zombies[0])
    count = 0
    if row == 0 or col == 0:
        return count
    visited = [[False for j in range(col)] for i in range(row)]
    for i in range(row):
        bol = False
        for j in range(row):
            if zombies[i][j] == '1' and visited[i][j] == False and visited[j][i] == False:
                visited[i][j] = True
                visited[j][i] = True
                DFS(j, visited, zombies, row)
                if bol == 0:
                    count += 1
                    bol = True
    return count


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # array input of zombie
    zombie_array = list()
    zombie_count = int(input())
    for i in range(int(zombie_count)):
        n = raw_input()
        zombie_array.append(str(n))

# zombie_array = ["1100" ,"1110", "0110", "0001"]
# print out the result
print(zombieCluster(zombie_array))
```

I am writing a test code (test_q4.py) for this code given below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unittest
import os
import sys

BASEDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), ".."))
sys.path.insert(0, BASEDIR)

from q4 import zombieCluster


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def testzombieCluster(self):
        zombie_array = ["1100", "1110", "0110", "0001"]
        expect = 2
        result = zombieCluster(zombie_array)
        self.assertEqual(result, expect)


if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main()
```

But when I run this command `python test_q4.py` from console, it is giving an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_q4.py", line 9, in <module>
    from q4 import zombieCluster
  File "/home/rowle/Desktop/python/solution/q4.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(zombieCluster(zombie_array))
NameError: name 'zombie_array' is not defined
```

When I removed `print(zombieCluster(zombie_array))` from source code, my test runs well, but if I remove this line , I will not see any output.

In this circumstances, What should I do in test code ?
Furthermore, How can I test the **main** function of source code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a def main() and put down the code as like:

```
def main():
    # array input of zombie
    zombie_array = list()
    zombie_count = int(input())
    for i in range(int(zombie_count)):
        n = raw_input()
        zombie_array.append(str(n))

    # zombie_array = ["1100" ,"1110", "0110", "0001"]
    # print out the result
    print(zombieCluster(zombie_array))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```